# Is there a non-zero measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

1) Everywhere one can find many things about Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
But what about arbitary measure? Is there a non-zero measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are measurable?

2) Another variant of the question:

Is there a measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the measure of a unit square is one, the measure is invariant under isometries and all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are measurable?

**EDITED:** I miss one important condition that a mesure of any bounded set should be finite.

Comment: To answer 1): Let $m(\varnothing)=0$ and $m(A)=\infty$ for all $A\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: 2) can be easily answered using an analogue of Vitali set.

Comment: Okay, I mean something non-trivial for the question 1.

Comment: As non-trivial measure for 1), there is the counting measure

Comment: Yes, sure. But if I add the condition that the measure of the unit square is 1?

Comment: An answer to 1) with unit square having measure $1$ would be any dirac measure of a point in the unit square. (Let $p$ be such a point and $m(A)=1$ iff $p\in A$, $0$ otherwise.)